# What's up with the libqtrpc2-1 / rds package in the archives?

Tags: package-management, application-development

I am considering using [libqtrpc2-1 [image: Install libqtrpc2-1]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/libqtrpc2-1) in my application **but** there seems to be some confusion over the name of the package.

On the right-hand side of [the package page](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/libqtrpc2-1), we see:

[image]

So it looks like the package is named "rds".

...or is it? Attempting to view the `copyright` file [results in a 404](http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/universe/r/rds/rds_1.1.0-0ubuntu1/libqtrpc2-1.copyright). The `changelog` file however, [loads fine](http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/universe/r/rds/rds_1.1.0-0ubuntu1/changelog). The link for bug reports contains "rds" in the URL.

It gets worse - the `-devel` package contains a directory in `/usr/include` that is named `qtrpc2` **not** `rds`. This is confusing to say the least.

So what *is* the name of this package? And what's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `libqtrpc2-1` binary package is built from the `rds` source package, as is listed on [Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/rds)
It's quite common for source packages to build a number of binary packages, some of which may not appear to have a related name.

Comment: Ah, that *totally* explains it (well, except for the 404 on the `copyright` file). Thank you.